# EmitSound delay

Tags: sound

I am experiencing a long delay (6 sec) between evaluating an `EmitSound` expression and the actual sound output. This may have happened after upgrading to Mma 10.0.2 or OSX Yosemite. Has anyone else experienced this? Are there any fixes? Here is an example:

```
EmitSound[Sound[SoundNote[]]]
```

Comment: With Mathematica 10.0.2.0 on Windows 8.1 (64x), I typically experience no noticeable delay.  However, I ran this code once while my virus checker was scanning my disk, and the delay was several seconds.

Comment: I'm afraid I too can only report on the result obtained with win8.1/V10.0.2 and other than the delay while executing this for the first time I don't perceive any delay. If anything this is a MacOS related issue.

Comment: On OSX 10.8.5 this seems to run normally.

Comment: Do you get unexpected delays between sounds if you chain sounds together? `EmitSound[{Sound[SoundNote[]],Sound[SoundNote[]],Sound[SoundNote[]]}]`